# Match aspect ratio to uploadable images

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a div element within my webpage, with the id "glCanvas". I want to be able to match it's aspect ratio to that of a photo that a user uploads:

```js
 $("#imageInput").change(function() {
            readBackgroundFile(this);
            readExif(this, function(data) {
                aspectRatio = data.width/data.height;
                height = $("#glCanvas").height();
                width = $("#glCanvas").width();
                newWidth = height*aspectRatio;
                console.log(data.focalLength);
                halfWidth = newWidth/2;
                FOV = 2 * Math.atan(halfWidth*0.5, data.focalLength);
                camera.aspect(aspectRatio);
                $("#glCanvas").width(newWidth);
                renderer.setSize(newWidth, height);

                viewerPosition = new THREE.Vector3().fromArray(llhxyz(data.latitude, data.longitude, data.altitude));
                updateScenePlacement();
            });
```

I think maybe the style.CSS may be the issue:

```css
#glCanvas{
background-color: black;
width: 650px;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
height: 500px;
```

So i tried deleting it, but unfortunately that removed it all together. What do i do?